# I want to change the Sublime text 3 python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, macos-mojave

I use python 3.7 with MacOS Mojave and try to use sublime text, I had problems with the python path but now I know where's the interpreter I need but I don't know how to change the interpreter of sublime text.

When I try to build code it shows this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /Users/julian/Documents/Ficheros_Python/calculadora/tenor.py on line 98, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/julian/Documents/Ficheros_Python/calculadora/tenor.py"]
[dir: /Users/julian/Documents/Ficheros_Python/calculadora]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin]
```

I know that the interpreter I need is in `/usr/local/bin/python3.7` or that's the location that Pycharm shows, I only need to change the python interpreter in Sublime but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text uses its [build systems](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) functionality to execute your python code. It selects a build system depending on the scope of your file, which can be changed by changing the syntax of your file. For python files, the scope is `source.python` and the associated build system essentially looks like this:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
}
```

There are several ways to change the python interpreter that Sublime Text invokes.

- Change the python interpreter that is invoked by the system's default `python` command to refer to another python interpreter. If your python executables are in `/usr/local/bin`, you could do:

  ```
  unlink /usr/local/bin/python
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
  ```

  However, this might adversely affect other applications that depend on a specific version of your default python interpreter.
- Create a python build system for your specific interpreter. To this end, go to `Preferences > Browse Packages` and create a file `User/Python3.7.sublime-build` containing:

  ```
  {
      "shell_cmd": "\"python3.7\" -u \"$file\"",
      "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
      "selector": "source.python",
  }
  ```

  After doing so, Sublime will show a popup to ask you what build system you want to use, as there are two build systems now for the `source.python` scope.

  With a little extra creativity, you can connect the new build system to the `Ctrl+b` shortcut by default, such that the build system selection popup doesn't appear any more. To realize this, you should add a named variant to the build system that you just created in `User/Python3.7.sublime-build`, by adding:

  ```
  "variants": [{"name": "Python3.7",}],
  ```

  Then, add the following shortcut via `Preferences > Key Bindings`:

  ```
  {
      "keys": ["ctrl+b"], 
      "context": [{"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python"}],
      "command": "build", "args": { "variant": "Python3.7" },
  },
  ```

  When necessary, the popup to select from the available build systems can still be invoked via the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+b`.